# Why isn't break good enough?

Tags: c++, loops, break

C++

When I first ran this code with a different input value of 881, 643, 743, etc... which are all primes numbers, I got a result of "True" but when I input a higher number like 804047277, it came back as "True" when it should have been "False"

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int num;

    std::cin >> num;

    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++){
        if(num % i == 0){
            std::cout << "True" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "False" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I corrected my code (The code below) and received the correct answer, which was "False"

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int num;

    std::cin >> num;

    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++){
        if(num % i == 0){
            std::cout << "True" << std::endl;
            break;
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "False" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't the break in the if statement stop the loop overall? I am just trying to understand why the break wasn't good enough, and I had to return 0;

Comment: Is it possible that the large number was more than the maximum value for an integer and that it rolled around to something else, yielding what seemed to be an incorrect answer?

Comment: Some insight can be gained by debugging. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/zT45Tqsr7)

Comment: Since both clauses of the `if()`/`else` statement break the loop, why do you need a loop at all?

Comment: The only thing either of those programs check is if the number is evenly divisible by 2, then they exit because true or false both break the loop in the first iteration. The only difference between the first and second is that the second should cause a non reachable code warning for the return after the break.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I don't think that would be the case. INT can hold a value of 2 billion were as the input value that gave me the wrong answer was only 800 million

Comment: Running the top program and inputting `804047277` to stdin prints `False` for me; are you sure that is the same code that you saw print `True` ?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner When I run it I keep getting false unless I put return 0; in the first if statement

Comment: @d743 Unless there's something very wrong with your compiler, that is not logically possible.  It is far more likely that you are mistaken and that you are not running the *exact* code that you've posted here.

Comment: I read the description again. "When I first ran this code with a different input value of 881, 643, 743, etc... which are all primes numbers, I got a result of "True"" If you saw "True" with any of the numbers in your question running either of the programs in the question you definitely have a problem as none of them are evenly divisible by 2. https://ideone.com/kkZgId I suspect you changed your code somehow, broke it, and failed to test the other numbers again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would correct your code like following (see description afterwards):

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/sxPj6KdM4)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    std::cin >> num;
    
    for (int i = 2; i < num; ++i)
        if (num % i == 0) {
            std::cout << "True (Composite)" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }

    std::cout << "False (Prime)" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
804047277
```

Output:

```
True (Composite)
```

As it is easy to understand, your program is intended to check [primality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime) and [compositness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number) of a number.

Mistake in your program is that you show `False (Prime)` when division by a very first `i` gives non-zero remainder. Instead, to actually check primality, you need to divide by all possible `i` and only if ALL of them give non-zero, then number is prime. It means that you shouldn't break or show False on very first non-zero remainder.

If ANY of `i` gives zero remainder then given number by definition is composite. So unlike the Prime case, this Composite case should `break` (or `return`) on very first occurance of zero remainder.

In code above on very first zero remainder I finish program showing to console that number is composite (True).

And only if whole loop finishes (all possible divisors are tested) then I show False (that number is prime).

Regarding question if `break;` is enough to finish a loop, then Yes, after break loop finishes and you don't need to `return 0;` after break, this return statement never finishes.

Also it is well known fact that it is enough to check divisibility until divisor equal to `Sqrt(num)`, which will be much faster. So your loop `for (int i = 2; i < num; ++i)` should become `for (int i = 2; i * i <= num; ++i)` which is square times faster.

Comment: @d743 If it was correct answer to your question, then don't forget to Accept this as valid answer. To Accept someone's answer just go to the top of text of my answer, and to the left-handside of top there is a Check-Mark (which is colored to green when clicked), click on it to make this answer accepted. Accepted answer means that it correctly answers your question, or at least was very close to what you wanted to know.